# How to connect minio when build Dockerfile Nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, minio

Can not connect with minio when I build project by Dockerfile. Everything working when I run project by script node.

```
const minioConfig = {
    endPoint: process.env.domain_minio || process.env.domain;
    port: Number(process.env.port_endPoint) || 9001,
    useSSL: false,
    accessKey: process.env.accessKey,
    secretKey: process.env.secretKey
}
const minioClient = new Minio.Client(minioConfig);
```

But when I create

```
minioClient.bucketExists(minioBucketAvatar, function(error, exists) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    if (exists) {
      return console.log('Bucket exists.', minioBucketAvatar)
    }
    else {
        minioClient.makeBucket(minioBucketAvatar, 'us-east-1', function(err) {
            if (err) return console.log('Error creating bucket.', minioBucketAvatar, err)
            console.log('Bucket created successfully in "us-east-1".', minioBucketAvatar)
        })
    }

});
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10
RUN npm install -g nodemon
WORKDIR /api_kgp
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD node index.js
#Expose port and start application
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

This is error when I build project by Dockerfile. Everything working when I run project by script node.

```
Error creating bucket. avatar { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT IP:9000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
```

Comment: Can you show your `Dockerfile` ?

Comment: @PierreB.I updated. Pls help me

Comment: Which step of your build is failing exactly? Can you show the complete stack?

Answer (score -1):

Please change the name of the "**endPoint**" prop to "**endpoint**" in "minioConfig".